# Vacuum persistance amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral

E. Fradkin's [Field Theories in Condensed Matter Physics](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/condensed-matter-physics-nanoscience-and-mesoscopic-physics/field-theories-condensed-matter-physics-2nd-edition) formulas 3.57 and 3.58:

I feel really sad about it, but all my tries of getting from formula

$$
Z = \operatorname{tr} \hat{T} \prod_{j=1}^{N_t}e^{i\Delta_t H(t_j)}
$$

to

$$
Z = \sum_{\{\alpha_j\}} \prod_{j=1}^{N_t} <\alpha_j|e^{-i\Delta_t H(t_j)} |\alpha_{j+1}>
$$

led to nothing. Can anyone show more precise transformation or give some clues please.

Comment: Please provide more context and indicate what the variables mean here.

Comment: @KyleArean-Raines , Vacuum persistence amplitude is $Z = \operatorname{tr} \hat{T} e^{i \int dt H(t)}$,  so the rest is how you transform integral to a sum: $\Delta_t$ - infinitesimal length, $N_t$ - number os segments. ${|\alpha_j>}$ - set of states at each time $t_j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the sum appears because of the completeness relation

$$\mathbf{1} = \sum_{\alpha} \left| \alpha \right> \left< \alpha \right|$$

taken over all the $\{ \alpha_j \}$ to give

$$\mathbf{1} = \sum_{\{ \alpha_j \}} \left| \alpha_j \right> \left< \alpha_j \right|$$

Starting with the first expression, which I believe you corrected in your comment to be the path integral

$$\mathrm{tr} ~\hat T ~e^{i \int dt H(t)}$$

if you make the segments finite length $\Delta t$ you can write it, for three segments, as

$$\hat T\sum_{\beta} \left< \beta \mid \exp{(\{i(H(t_1)\Delta t + H(t_2)\Delta t + H(t_3)\Delta t)\}} \mid \beta \right>$$

Inserting the completeness relation, you have

$$Z = \hat T\sum_{\beta}~\sum_{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3}\langle \beta \mid \alpha_1 \rangle \langle \alpha_1 \mid e^{i H_1 \Delta t} \mid \alpha_2 \rangle \langle \alpha_2 \mid e^{i H_2 \Delta t}\mid \alpha_3 \rangle \langle \alpha_3 \mid e^{i H_3 \Delta t} \mid \beta \rangle$$

The rest should be pretty straightforward. Generalize to $N_t$ segments and simplify. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: I bet $\hat T$ stands for _time ordering_ not _time reversal_ .